# Isn't Saint Lucia hat a bit dangerous?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014, winter-bash-2015

I think it would be nicer if we get safer hats next time.

Putting *burning* candles on my head!?

[image]

<sub>Good thing that *imitation crab* is not alive.</sub>

Comment: hate to alarm you, but the candles aren't real.... tried to use hem when my lights were out and tripped over the vacuum and landed on the washing machine.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk0FyZqNp5Q

Comment: This hat is safe till you try less movement. Or lern Rajasthani folk dance, they dance with keeping burning Dia's and all on their heads.

Comment: I find it to be the most beautiful hat! :)

Comment: This question was a feature-request. Apparently there are safe-hat haters. or dangerous-hat lovers?

Answer (score 10):

Isn't this one even more dangerous?

[image: Solstice]

Here, for your daily dose of wisdom, [xkcd has a few words to say](https://what-if.xkcd.com/89/):

> the Sun is one of the meltiest things in the Solar System.

[image]

Oh, also, the Red Shirt is likely to get you killed assuming it's a reference to Star Trek.

I'm bored, so why not. Have a haiku:

Candles are burny
Sun is hot and burny too
Warning: [do not eat](http://www.theonion.com/articles/health-department-still-not-able-to-really-prove-w,27278/)

Also, is your profile picture really any safer?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it both sun and moon? They might neutralize each other. However, I didn't get it yet, still on the safe(r) side :)

Comment: http://johngushue.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451f25369e2015435f2c2f6970c-pi

Comment: Well his hair is obviously on fire because a candle from the hat fell over.

Comment: My picture was the main reason to ask if you look carefully :)

Comment: *cough keyboardfire cough*