# Request for a specific new secret hat

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

[image: The Steelers Fan hat]

If you could make a hat of this guy, Steely McBeam (who we refer to as Steely Dan -- bonus points if that were the name), a certain set of people would be eternally grateful.

Also, word is there's people who would do ANYTHING to get this hat.

Comment: Anything? Then your best bet would probably be to get hired at SE and sneak it into next year's Winter Bash.

Comment: I don't think there's a hat for getting 10+ downvotes on a single post... maybe there is...

Comment: @enderland You can't get my score low enough to prevent me from posting. I'm starting to think that Meta needs a request for an upvote button to be implemented, though.

Comment: @Axelrod just don't post things people disagree with overwhelmingly.

Comment: What would one have to do to get this hat?

Comment: @enderland It was a joke, but for the record two of my three posts have been declared dupes of extremely well received questions.

Comment: Well, another +3 and you just might get a hat for it

Comment: I WOULD UPVOTE BUT OUTTA VOTES DAMMIT

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm wearing the hat you win. This is for a friend.

Comment: @nicael How about now? :D

Answer (score 10):

Look, I upvoted this [on principle](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/community-management-by-popular-demand-kevin-chang-joins-the-team/), but... no.

We already had Sparkles adorning a football helmet last year for the Handegg hat, and that's about as close as you're going to get.

It's a little too specific, and possibly even divisive. And after last year and this year, it seems another hat that people "would do ANYTHING" for might be the last thing we need.

There's no obvious trigger, either, although that's something that could be worked on.

Comment: In my defense, your hat triggers are the issue, not the hats themselves. Were you to require constructive things -- or even just things for fun, like posting in a certain thread -- you'd have a much better response.

Comment: They mostly are [supposed to be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271140/what-positive-behavior-is-each-hat-encouraging/271154#271154). There's definitely room for improvement. Suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: @Axelrod: No incentive has been devised that can not [also be abused](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/09.html).

Comment: @Pops A frenemy of mine has been dismayed that no hat for making a tag wiki has been made.  Instead of editting an old question or removing comments that don't have flags, you could consider *answering* an old question or removing comments that *do* have flags.

Comment: @JonEricson That's human nature. Rather than encouraging and discouraging the bad, however, it's generally more efficient to just encourage the good.